# class navbar-nav causing Issue - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

In MEAN stack application, `href` within class `navbar-nav` is causing an issue. Following is my code:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a  ng-show = "!main.isLoggedIn"  href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a ng-show = "!main.isLoggedIn" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false">Register <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/issuerregister">Issuer</a></li>
              <li><a href="/investorregister">Investor</a></li>
         </ul>               
      </li>
      <li><a ng-show = "main.isLoggedIn"  href="#" ng-click="main.logout();" >Logout </a></li>
  </ul>
```

The page is rendered correctly, but I'm getting an error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /

If I remove the class `navbar-nav` error disappears. Can anyone please suggest what's causing the issue?

Comment: That error sounds like it's caused by jQuery.

Comment: Please include any script that is using the `navbar-nav` class.  All you have provided so far is markup with angular attributes in it.

Comment: Need your JavaScript setup to get better understanding of issue. But i think this is because some plugin is handling navbar behavior and it is expecting ids in href in the form of '#id' instead of a url.

Comment: Thanks...When I removed one plugin issue resolved.. : )